# Do I need to create a network explicitly for docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have been trying to understand docker and the swarm mode.I also read about the docker network tutorials.
I have tried the docker swarm mode.If a docker swarm mode is initialised and if we execute `docker network ls` it shows a network with the name ingress.
My question is do I need to exclusively create an overlay network?Or should the swam mode work fine without exclusively creating a network?

Comment: When you run different services / stacks, communicate with each other  in swarm mode best practice is to create the network explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is do I need to exclusively create an overlay network?Or should the swam mode work fine without exclusively creating a network?

No, you don't need to, however it is recommended that you create a custom overlay network for your applications that you deploy to the swarm. The `ingress` overlay network `handles control and data traffic related to swarm services`. From the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/):

> Use the default overlay network demonstrates how to use the default
>   overlay network that Docker sets up for you automatically when you
>   initialize or join a swarm. **This network is not the best choice for
>   production systems**.

Comment: So using ingress network itself works but because it handles control and data traffic related to swarm services it is not ok to use in production!?

Comment: @user1261913 yes

Comment: correct the best practice is to create one network for each "solution" you would host in a swarm, that is, all the services that need to talk to each other inside a single swarm. If you use compose files (aka stack files) with the docker stack command, it automatically does this for you (one overlay network created per stack by default).

Answer (score 1):

If you need communication between containers on different Docker Swarm Nodes, you need an overlay network.

If you just use "docker run" it will use the ingress network on the host you are running the command.